# where am ı doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, function, methods

Elements in an entered array, without breaking their order, but singularly.
Write a program that casts it into a new array. For example, if the input is {3, 3, 87,56,1, 87, 3, 2 } the output should be {3, 87, 56, 1, 2 }

I want to solve this question without using ready-made methods

`import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PassElementToAnotherArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    transferElementsOfArray();
}
public static int[] createArrays() {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter first array size:");
    int size = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) (Math.random()*100);
    }
        
    return array;
}
public static void transferElementsOfArray() {
    
    int [] firstArray = createArrays();
    System.out.println("Elements of the first array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(firstArray[i]+" ");
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    
    int sizeOfTheNewArray = 0;
    int [] newArray = new int[sizeOfTheNewArray];
    
    boolean isIt = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        
        for (int j = i+1; j < firstArray.length; j++) {
            
            if (firstArray[i]==firstArray[j]) {
                isIt = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                isIt = false;
            }
        }
        if (!isIt) {
            sizeOfTheNewArray++;
        }           
    }       
    System.out.println(sizeOfTheNewArray);
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < firstArray.length; j++) {
            if (firstArray[i]==firstArray[j]) {
                isIt = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                isIt = false;
            }
    }
    if (!isIt) {
        
        for (int j = counter; j < newArray.length; j++) {
            newArray[j] = firstArray[i];
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(newArray[i]);
    }
    
}
```

}`

when i do this i can't even see the elements of the new array in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several bugs and questionable design decisions, to start with

```
int sizeOfTheNewArray = 0;
int [] newArray = new int[sizeOfTheNewArray];
```

Means `newArray` is always empty. I would break the problem down into discrete sections, first count the unique elements in an array;

```
public static int countUniqueElements(int[] arr) {
    int count = 0;
    loop: for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    continue loop;
                }
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Next, you should *read* an array of values from the user. Let's write a method to do that. Read a line of comma separated values, split on comma and convert to an `int[]`.

```
public static int[] readArray(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your array values");
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
    int[] array = new int[tokens.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i].trim());
    }
    return array;
}
```

Now, we can write a method to actually get the unique elements of an array given an array. Start by counting the unique elements. Then create the new array. Finally, repeat the strategy we used in counting unique elements to populate the new array.

```
public static int[] getUniqueElements(int[] arr) {
    int sizeOfTheNewArray = countUniqueElements(arr);
    int[] newArray = new int[sizeOfTheNewArray];
    int count = 0;
    loop: for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    continue loop;
                }
            }
        }
        newArray[count] = arr[i];
        count++;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Now we can update `main` to invoke the above methods

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = readArray(scanner);
    System.out.printf("Before: %s%n", Arrays.toString(arr));
    int[] arr2 = getUniqueElements(arr);
    System.out.printf("After: %s%n", Arrays.toString(arr2));
}
```

And run it

```
Please enter your array values
3, 3, 87, 56, 1, 87, 3, 2 
Before: [3, 3, 87, 56, 1, 87, 3, 2]
After: [3, 87, 56, 1, 2]
```